# How To Use Preg Match

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

`$str = '11,22,33';`

`$str = '22,44,55;`

`$str = '66,22;`

how can i use preg match so that by matching 22 in any of string will yield output as 1 
i.e (for case 1 it should match ",22," for case 2 is shd match "22," , for case3 it should match ",22")

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an excuse not to read the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.  At least **try** to use this function... If you come across any problems - come ask a question about it...

Comment: if just searching for a string in a string strpos() is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '11,22,33';
$findme   = '22';
$pos = strpos($str, $findme);


if ($pos !== false) {
//found it
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
/,?22,?/
```

Comment: and how ?
can you write the syntax

Comment: Could you specify your issues with the syntax? You will just need to add this as a string to the preg_match patten parameter and then input your strings into the function as well to match the wanted parts of the strings.

Answer (score -1):

use php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. We want to bring great content *to* this site as opposed to sending users elsewhere to get their information.